# Where is netatalk config file on NAS4Free?

Tags: netatalk

Env: NAS4Free(10.2.0.2) on Athlon2 based whitebox PC.

I got a AFP file sharing problem with NAS4Free. Therefore I would like to check raw netatalk config on NAS4Free. By using File Manager of NAS4Free, I searched /etc directory. But I was not able to find a netatalk config file.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. /var/etc/ is an answer.